Error while implementing push notification in .net MAUI project
JAVA000 Error message in .net MAUI
I am trying to implement Push notification to my .net MAUI app, after installing packages
getting the JAVA000 error message message while building the project, I tried clean solution and reload the project but no use.
How to resolve this issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you please show the details about the error message? In addition, can you show the code in the csproj file and we can know the nuget packages you used.

Am trying to implement PUSH Notifications to my .net 8 MAUI application, When I install the below packages getting the bellow error when I build the project.
Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging
Xamarin.Google.Dagger
Xamarin.GoolgePlayService.Base
Error APT2260 resource mipmap/student (aka com.mipl.bits:mipmap/student) not found.
Error APT2067 failed processing manifest.

Did you have an image file named student? And did you set its build action as MauiIcon?
